# Matching special characters and letters in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters

I am trying to validate a string, that should contain letters numbers and special characters `&-._` only. For that I tried with a regular expression.

```
var pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9&_\.-]/
var qry = 'abc&*';
if(qry.match(pattern)) {
    alert('valid');
}
else{
    alert('invalid');
}
```

While using the above code, the string `abc&*` is valid. But my requirement is to show this invalid. ie Whenever a character other than a letter, a number or special characters `&-._` comes, the string should evaluate as invalid. How can I do that with a regex?

Comment: The key is to use `^` at the beginning and `+$` at the end, as the answers below have explained. `/^[a-zA-Z0-9&_\.-]+$/`. I'm pointing this out in case you missed that subtle difference.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Add them to the allowed characters, but you'll need to escape some of them, such as -]/\

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]*$/
```

That way you can remove any individual character you want to disallow.

Also, you want to include the start and end of string placemarkers ^ and $

**Update:**

As elclanrs understood (and the rest of us didn't, initially), the *only* special characters needing to be allowed in the pattern are &-._

```
/^[\w&.\-]+$/
```

[\w] is the same as [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Though the dash doesn't need escaping when it's at the start or end of the list, I prefer to do it in case other characters are added. Additionally, the + means you need at least one of the listed characters. If zero is ok (ie an empty value), then replace it with a * instead:

```
/^[\w&.\-]*$/
```

Comment: I would suggest that any list which allows all those special characters should allow spaces as well.

Comment: Plus (+) character doesn't work with this expression

Comment: @calbertts, do you mean where it's included in the list of characters in "var pattern..."? Which language are you using? Javascript?

Comment: @HighlyIrregular I've tried to match a string with a plus (+) with Javascript, but I've found it's not that easy, actually, I just gave up with this and made a separated validation.

Comment: @calbertts, when the + character is not in square brackets, it needs to be escaped or it gets treated as a wildcard character. As a wildcard, it means: match 1 or more of the previous character/group-of-characters (depending on if they are wrapped in round or square brackets etc). eg In the pattern /^[\w&.\-]+$/, the + character is being used as a wildcard.

Comment: With spaces:  ^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?\s]*$

Answer (score 20):

Well, why not just add them to your existing character class?

```
var pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9&._-]/
```

If you need to check whether a string consists of nothing but those characters you have to **anchor** the expression as well:

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9&._-]+$/
```

The added `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the string respectively.

Testing for letters, numbers or underscore can be done with `\w` which shortens your expression:

```
var pattern = /^[\w&.-]+$/
```

As mentioned in the comment from Nathan, if you're not using the results from `.match()` (it returns an array with what has been matched), it's better to use `RegExp.test()` which returns a simple boolean:

```
if (pattern.test(qry)) {
    // qry is non-empty and only contains letters, numbers or special characters.
}
```

**Update 2**

In case I have misread the question, the below will check if all three separate conditions are met.

```
if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(qry) && /[0-9]/.test(qry) && /[&._-]/.test(qry)) {
   // qry contains at least one letter, one number and one special character
}
```

Comment: +1. It might be worth mentioning to use `test` instead of `match`, since you don't really need the matches to be found. This could help performance, readability, and might help the asker learn something new.

Comment: Also, no slash after the `i`. `/[a-z]/i/` should be `/[a-z]/i`.

Answer (score 16):

Try this regex:

```
/^[\w&.-]+$/
```

Also you can use `test`.

```
if ( pattern.test( qry ) ) {
  // valid
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let pattern = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/;

//following will give you the result as true(if the password contains Capital, small letter, number and special character) or false based on the string format

let reee =pattern .test("helLo123@");   //true as it contains all the above
```

Comment: could you please a) format you code as code and b) add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx: Matching special charecters which we use in paragraphs and alphabets

```
   Javascript : /^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\,\.\-_ \/)(:][a-zA-Z_ ])?[a-zA-Z_ .]*)*$/.test(str)

                .test(str) returns boolean value if matched true and not matched false

            c# :  ^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\,\.\-_ \/)(:][a-zA-Z_ ])?[a-zA-Z_ .]*)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bunch of these but none of them worked for all of my tests. So I found this:

```js
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,15}$
```

from this source: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/password-validation.php

Answer (score 0):

Here you can match with special char:

```
function containsSpecialChars(str) {
  const specialChars = /[`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;
  return specialChars.test(str);
}

console.log(containsSpecialChars('hello!')); // ️ true
console.log(containsSpecialChars('abc')); // ️ false
console.log(containsSpecialChars('one two')); // ️ false
```