# Regular expression to match any characters including line breaks in a string using java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which includes line breaks in java .I need a regular expression to match any characters including line breaks.

Here is the string:

```
String s= "Hello World".(line break)
       Note= amount"
```

I am using this `(.*?)` but it won't match line breaks.

Comment: You can use `"(?s).*` to match any character where `s` is for `DOTALL`.

Comment: It means I need to replace  (.*?) with this (?s).*

Comment: You can always use a tool like regerx.com to test your regular expression.

Comment: Yes `s.match( "(?s).*" );`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this pattern:

```
([a-zA-Z\n])+
```

Tested on [regexr](http://regexr.com/). This is an example of how to implement it in Java

```
String pattern = "([a-zA-Z\n])+";
String input = "String with \n line break.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
```

Comment: I have a special characters

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946651/matching-special-characters-and-letters-in-regex) question for a complete explanation