# regex for allowing only certain special characters and also including the alphanumerical characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm struggling with REGEX and require it for a program.

The input require only alphanumerical keys and also (allow only comma,:,space,/,- in special chars)

I have tried = (^[a-zA-Z0-9,:\S/-]*$)
  As far as i understand and please correct me if I'm wrong.
  a-zA-Z0-9 - The alphanumerical keys.
  ,:        - Comma and colon
  \S        - Space 
  /        - I'm not sure how to represent a forward slash thus i escaped it
  -        - Dash also not sure if it is needed to escape it.

Would be appreciated if this can be corrected and also a explanation of each part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946651/matching-special-characters-and-letters-in-regex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can replace `a-zA-Z0-9` with just `\\w` which is short for `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`. Furthermore, `\\S` is any character, but not a whitespace, you should use a `\\s` instead. You don't need to escape `/`, and even `-` if it's the first one or the last one, because if it's placed between two characters it could be interpreted as range and you'll have to escape it. So, you can make your regex like `^([\w,:\s/-]*)$`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply helped alot.

Answer (score 5):

1. The `\S` shorthand matches any character except whitespace, just the opposite of what you want. Lowercase `\s` matches whitespace `[\t\v\n\r\f ]`. But if you only want spaces, just put a space in the character class.
2. a hyphen `-` needs to be escaped inside characters, unless it's the first or last character in the character class, but you could always escape it just to be sure.
3. Slashes `/` don't need to be escaped. They're escaped in other languages where you use them as pattern delimiters. ie: `/regex/i`.
4. Besides hyphens and shorthands, only backslashes `\\` and closing brackets `\]` need to be escaped.
5. Remember in [java](/questions/tagged/java), you always need to use double backslashes (one is interpreted by java, the other by the regex engine).

**Regex**

```
pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,:/\\-]*$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the Start of Line `^` and End of Line `$` outside the group - like

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9,:\S/-]*)$
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply ,but tried this it still allowed #$%!#  not sure if i was implementing it correctly.

Comment: That's because I missed the fact that Stanislav pointed out - the `\S` was a capital `S` ;)