# Character matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, regex-negation

I need to match a string to have words and not numbers, I need to match special characters such as $!:{}_ if they are part of the word but ignore otherwise.

I have a regex that matches for word and ignores numbers but cannot work out how to match special characters if they are part of the word but ignore otherwise.

Here is what I have correctly - `/^d\s+/`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946651/matching-special-characters-and-letters-in-regex

Comment: what do you mean by  `match special characters if they are part of the word but ignore otherwise.`

Comment: If you use any online regex tester, you will see that [`^d\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/dN8iM5/1) makes very little sense given your requirements.

Comment: Can include example string at Question?

Comment: Example string: This is a test of 1,2,3 word-count - test. So in this example I would expect it to match: This is a test of word-count test it should ignore 1,2,3 and the - that is on its own as it is not part of a word.

Comment: Then try `/\b[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)\b/ig`.

Comment: I have now been given a proper brief:

Allow words and letters only, and ignore any numbers.
Special characters such as (-_‘[]{}“£$&%!:;\/) should either be ignored or treated as part of the word they sit within.

Answer (score 0):

> Allow words and letters only, and ignore any numbers. Special
>   characters such as (-_‘[]{}“£$&%!:;/) should either be ignored or
>   treated as part of the word they sit within.

Try using `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\s\d+.*\d|\s+[^a-z]/ig` to replace space character followed by digit followed by any character followed by digit , or space character followed by any character not a-z case insensitive

```js
var str = "This is a test of 1,2,3 word-count - test.";

str = str.replace(/\s\d+.*\d|\s+[^a-z]/ig, "");

document.body.textContent = str;
```